# try catch finally understanding check

Tags: java

I've found this subject very confusing was wondering if i could get some feedback to see if I understand this concept.

if you do something like
    int x = "this is not an int"
java will complain and throw a crash error when you try to run it, in this case "static error". so if 
I wanted to create a exception handler for this it would be something like this?

```
try 
 {
  int x = "this is not an int"
 }catch(Staticerror nameIcanMakeUp){ 
  x = 4}
 finally{
```

does the x has to be set to a acceptable value in the catch to prevent a crash?
does the first argument of catch have to be the same as what java would say when it crashes? 
do I put the rest of the code in the finally block should I have more code after the bit of code that might throw exceptions?
also how would I do this with a exception I want to define like if its an age field and I don't want people entering dates from the future etc?

Comment: That will not throw an exception, it will lead to a compiler error. Check this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/

Answer (score 2):

> if you do something like int x = "this is not an int" java will complain

Java is a statically typed language so it picks up these error at compile time, not when you run the program.

> and throw a crash error when you try to run it,

Actually the `javac` compiler gives you the error.

> I wanted to create a exception handler for this it would be something like this?

There is no way to ignore code which doesn't compile at runtime as you can't run a program which didn't compile.

What you can do is something like this.

```
Object o = "This is not an Integer";
Integer i = (Integer) o;
```

This does compile and produces a runtime rather than a compile time error.  You can catch this with

```
Object o = "This is not an Integer";
try {
    Integer i = (Integer) o;
} catch(ClassCastException cce) {
    cce.printStackTrace();
}
```

> does the x has to be set to a acceptable value in the catch to prevent a crash?

The code in the `catch` block also has to compile and run without throwing an Exception.

> does the first argument of catch have to be the same as what java would say when it crashes?

The class you try to catch has to be the class of the exception or a super class.

> do I put the rest of the code in the finally block

It depends, but usually you don't need a finally block.

> should I have more code after the bit of code that might throw exceptions?

It depends on what you are trying to do but usually you put as little in this block as possible.

> also how would I do this with a exception I want to define like if its an age field and I don't want people entering dates from the future etc?

You can create you own custom Exception by extending an existing one, but I tend to re-use the existing ones like

```
if (age < 0)
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Age cannot be negative");
```